# Python: How is my set being turned into a list?

Tags: python

I've written a program to recursively get all the hyponym-children of a given synset in the wordnet graph.

However, that is not relevant to my question here.

I'm basically adding all the nodes I pass through to a set.
The output I'm getting, however, is a list

Here's my code

```
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

feeling = wn.synset('feeling.n.01')
happy = wn.synset('happiness.n.01')

def get_hyponyms(li):
    return [x.hyponyms() for x in li]

def flatten(li):
    return [item for sublist in li for item in sublist]

def get_hyponyms_list(li):
    if li:
        return list(set(flatten(get_hyponyms(li))))

def get_the_hyponyms(li, hyps):
    if li:
        hyps |= set(li)
        get_the_hyponyms(get_hyponyms_list(li), hyps)
    return hyps

def get_all_hyponyms(li):
    hyps = set()
    return get_the_hyponyms(li, hyps)

feels = sorted(get_all_hyponyms([feeling]))
print type(feels)
```

The output is this-

```
<type 'list'>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `sorted()` creates a list

Comment: Because `sorted` returns a list. It can't return a set, because sets are not ordered.

Comment: If you are expecting to get a sorted set back then you mis-understand sets.  They are not, and cannot be, ordered.

Comment: Yes, yes... It was an oversight on my part. I forgot about the sorted() method.

Comment: @NikhilPrabhu: `sorted()` is a built-in function, not a method.  Which is kinda the point.  Unlike the `list.sort()` method, `sorted()` will sort any iterable, but whatever that object is it will only return a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted()` creates a list, if you do a simple test, this behavior is clear. The Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) says a "set object is an *unordered* collection of distinct hashable objects".

```
>>> x = {1,3,2}
>>> sorted(x)
[1, 2, 3]
```